# Concat operator must be surrounded by spaces

Tags: php, module, drupal-7

I have been working on a Drupal project and I want to make sure that pass all the coding standards. And its unclear to me what is asking me in here. And I have been researching for a while and I don't find the answer. On the line 4 error said, "Concat operator must be surrounded by spaces."

```
function zipalters_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3.0,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module ', 'zipalters') .'/includes',
  );
}
```

Can someone tell me how my code should look like?

Remember this is the line

```
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module ', 'zipalters') .'/includes',
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer in [Drupal.org forum](https://www.drupal.org/node/2334263#comment-9127089). I need a space between the dot and the quote:

```
'path' => drupal_get_path('module ', 'zipalters') . '/includes',
```